# If I keep a reference to a Runnable, when does the Thread it ran on get released?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

If I have a `Runnable` like this:

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
    int helloCount = 0;
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
        helloCount++;
    }
}
```

And another class like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HelloRunnable hello = new HelloRunnable();
        (new Thread(hello)).start();
        // do some other stuff
        System.out.println("Numer of times I said Hello: " + hello.helloCount);
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, the thread stops its execution after it prints the Hello and increments the counter (let's assume it gets executed right away). The instance of HelloRunnable should still exist while I do the other stuff, since I have a valid pointer to it.

But when is the Thread object (the one I passed my Runnable to) released? Could I create a big number of threads like this, maintaining my Runnable objects (each thread with its own Runnable), or would threads never get released while the Runnable object exists and I would run out of threads or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Runnable has no rererence to the thread that called it, so it won't keep the thread from being garbage collected. There is nothing magic about the Runnable, it's more or less just a convention how to provide a thread with the code to run.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After the Runnable finishes, if the Runnable had a class member variable,  can i still access it, rather than relying on Callable returning a value?

Comment: @djangofan as long as you keep a reference to the runnable, you can access it like you access any other java object.

Comment: @Erich Kitzmueller I tried it here and couldn't get it to work:  https://repl.it/@djangofan/RunnableSavingFieldAfterFinishjava